# Why do developers sometimes generate a dynamic form and post it, while ajax post is readily available?

Tags: angularjs, http, post, http-method

```
    var post = function() {
      angular.element('body').append('<form name="name" action="http://webservice.com">')
      angular.element('form[name="myForm"]').append(function(){
        var toAppend = '';
        angular.forEach([paramkey: paramValue],function(param,key){
          toAppend += '<input type="hidden" id="' + key + '" name="' + key + '" value="' + param + '">';
        });
        return toAppend;
      }).submit();

    };
```

I see this being used by fellow developers, and I was wondering why add all these when a $http({method: 'POST'}) will do the dirty work.

the result of this is that it downloads a passbook file.

I tried to replicate this call with $.ajax, and the file is not retrieved, is there a special header that i am missing?

Comment: It's possible their webservice expects actual form data and not just POSTed json.

Comment: there's no difference as far as http can tell right? if user were to change to form-encoded.

Comment: They are different. And processed differently by the backend, it does matter.

Comment: ok, do you have a link to share that explain these differences?

Comment: When you post a form the data ends up in the body of the request in name/value format, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data   When you post json, the data is still in the body of the request, but it is in json format, and not in name/value format, so the backend has to know (or determine via headers) what to expect. And likely there are many backends written before json became popular, so they may only support traditional form data.

Comment: actually in network this is appended on to become params... not sure why